# return a value in javascript help needed

Tags: javascript

I have this line of code:

```html
<a href="#" id="profilelink" name="link2" onClick="viewornot(<?php echo $freechat_id ?>)"><?php echo $freechat_list; ?></a>
<!-- call the JS onclick and if OK was click do the message box and send button here -->
```

Then I have my JS:

```
function viewornot(id) {
    var e = confirm('Do you want to view this profile?');
    if (e == true) {
        window.location.href = "http://www-rainbowcode-net/apps_dev.php/profiles/showprofilepersonal?id=" + id;
        window.location('http://www-rainbowcode-net/apps_dev.php/profiles/showprofilepersonal?id=' + id);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        var e2 = confirm('Do you want to send a message?');
        if (e2 == true) {
            //if ok was clicked send value back?? 
            return e2;  
        }
    }
}
```

on the e2 confirm: if I clicked OK how can I send a value back(so that I know OK was clicked) so that I can then produce the message box and send button and do the rest of the code to send a message?

Comment: What value do you want to send back and where does it need to go?

Comment: back to where i called the onclick from cos i need to know if OK was clicked so i can do the message box and send button so user can send a message :) i just want to send SOME value back if OK was clicked on the confirm   thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `onClick="viewornot(...)"` to `onClick="return viewornot(...)"`.

Comment: thank you i had it like that but how do i now check it? meaning what would the code be please? i have no idea...still trying to make sense of all this thank you

Comment: What do you want to happen when `viewornot` returns true, and what do you want to happen when it returns false?

Comment: i have my code like this now: 
    <a href="#" id="profilelink" name="profilelink" onClick="return viewornot(<?php echo $freechat_id ?>)"><?php echo $freechat_list; ?></a>
                             
    <?php
       if (isset($_POST['profilelink']) == 1)
       {                           
           echo "ok was clicked";
       }
    ?>
and my js: 
    var e2 = confirm('Do you want to send a message?');
    if (e2 == true)
    {
       document.getElementById('profilelink').value = 1;
       return 1;
    } 

but it is still not working it does not do the echo "ok was clicked"   pls help?

Comment: if it returns true, i know user wants to send a message thus i will do the code for a message box and a send button and send the message  please help? thank you